# Replace some text to bold in django template

Tags: python, django, replace, django-templates

I have a variable

```
text = "replace some word"
```

in a view. I want to replace `'some'` to bold. Like this:

```
"replace **some** word"
```

How to handle that variable in django template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, the `**` do not make a bold string in a template and you will have a much harder time trying to replace these markers with appropriate opening and closing tags in the template, e.g via a custom filter. However, you can make it bold in the view by applying the necessary HTML there and [marking it safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe):

```
# views.py
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

# in your view
# ...
text = "replace some word"
# add the appropriate html tags
text = text.replace('some', '<strong>some</strong>')
# now you have to mark it as safe so the tags will be rendered as tags
text = mark_safe(text)
# ...
return render(reqest, template, {.., 'text': text, ...})
```

Now you can just use it like a normal variable in the template via `{{ text }}`

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom template tags to render these type of things. You have to write some extra lines of code. But once you do, it's reusable and less tedious to use replace function every time.

Create a custom tag/filter file called **mytags.py**, your app layout might look like this:

```
myapp/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    templatetags/
        __init__.py
        mytags.py
    views.py
```

Write in **mytags.py**:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

def bold(text):
    return text.replace('**','<strong>',1).replace('**','</strong>',1)

register.filter('bold', bold)
```

In your template, first load the custom tag file:

```
{% load mytags %}
```

Apply this custom tag to the text:

```
{{ text|bold }}
```

For reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/